# Execute a included exe with C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

Since I'm not able to know why my clickOnce application is not able to verify If the prerequisite is already installed on the Target PC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614637/prerequisite-visual-studio-2012.

I'm wondering if I can include the Redistribuable Visual C++ pour Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (vcredist_x86.exe) into my application and at Run time I`ll check if the product is installed with the ProductCode and than Execute the vcredist_x86.exe

Do you think that it's a good way to do ?

Thanks

Comment: _'Do you think that it's a good way to do ?'_ No. Usually this is done by the installer of your application.

Comment: You could instead just include the required DLLs in your app's install folder rather than actually installing vcredist.

Comment: @mclaassen I'll try you suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just including the necessary DLLs which are part of the required VC Redistributable version in your application's installation folder. If your app is linked to one of those DLLs it will be default search the current working directory of the application for it first before looking in the standard installation directory in C:\Windows\...

Comment: Copying the file Fix the problem, but my colleague told me that it's not a good way to copy Microsoft files at the same folder as the EXE (mfc110.dll, mfcu110.dll...), besides these files are all ready in two different folder (Microsoft.VC90.CRT and Microsoft.VC90.MFC) in the same folder as the exe, I don't know why the exe didn't search there !!

Comment: I think it only searches the directory at the same level as the .exe file and won't go recursively into other directories at the same level (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I thought adding #define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_MFC_VERSION 1
#define _BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION 1 will permit to search on the folder, I miss understand what my colleague told me, anyway just to let you know that your suggestion is good even on Microsoft web site : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx last 2 lines first paragraph --Thanks